# Gnuplot: how to plot single points with custom xlabels

Tags: plot, gnuplot, points

my problem is the following, I have a text file like that:

```
#X,#Y 
1,1.00182349
2,4.024570000000001
3,8.73499
```

What I want to get is a plot like that:

[image]

where, basically, each y value is plotted as distinct point and on the x-axis my label are N,L,H.

I made that picture with the plot command in octave, but I'm forced to do that with gnuplot.

Please, can someone tell me how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify arbitrary label for the tic labels:

```
set datafile separator comma
set logscale    y
set xtics ("N" 1, "L" 2, "H" 3)
plot "test.dat" using 1:2:1 notitle with points linecolor variable pointtype 5 pointsize 2
```

[image]